# How to parse/split this line while keeping note of the order?

Tags: c#, regex, split

A little stuck here. I have a simple question I guess.

Given the following input:

```
 content {c:comment comment}this is actual content{c:comment etc} content
```

I need a way to get the content and comments seperated, but I need to now the order of them. So a simple regex doesn't work.

I want to get this:

```
 content
 {c:comment comment}
 this is actual content
 {c:comment etc}
 content
```

Somebody a clue?

Comment: Can't you replace "{" by "\n{" and "}" by "}\n"?

Comment: I would end up with a white empty line if the {c:comment} would be before the first content.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a huge price. You can trim that line out if you really want, or make the regex ignore ^{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = "content {c:comment comment}this is actual content{c:comment etc} content";
var split = Regex.Split(s, @"\{c:(?<comment>[^\}]*)\}");
```

NOTE: when the regex of a split has a capturing like `(?<comment>   )` it also gets returned.

Comment: Ended up with: List<string> Regex.Split(input "{|}"). comments kept the "c:this is a comment" "c:" so I could recognize if it was a comment. Didn't think of Regex it's Split method. So this helped.

Answer (score 2):

As Artelius suggested:

```
Regex.Replace(
Regex.Replace(input, "({)", @"\r\n$1"),
                     "(})", @"$1\r\n");
```

Comment: No, because you want a newline BEFORE { but AFTER }.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(.*?)\s*{c:\s*(.*?)}\s*` gave me a string[] with the items: `'content', 'comment comment', 'this is actual content', 'comment etc', 'content'`

Maybe that's close to what you're looking for.